# FactoryGirl: Factory not registered

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, factory-bot

I work on a project with a structure like:

```
projects/warehouse/core
projects/warehouse/products/bottles
projects/warehouse/products/boxes
```

In this project, the application logic, gems, etc. are all in the `core` application.  I have `boxes` set up for rspec like such:

```
projects/warehouse/products/boxes/spec
    /factories
    /models
```

The `factories` directory contains `cubics.rb`:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :cubic
    id 1
    dimension 12
  end
end
```

The `models` directory contains `cubic_spec.rb`:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Boxes::Cubic do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    FactoryGirl.create(:cubic).should be_valid
  end
end
```

The `Cubic` model is located in `products/boxes/app/models/boxes/cubic.rb`.

```
module Boxes
  class Cubic < BoxExBase
    self.table_name = 'containers'
    #validation stuff goes here
  end
end
```

Simple and straightforward.  When I execute `rspec ../products/boxes/spec/models/cubic_spec.rb` I get the ArgumentError: Factory not registered: cubic.  I've tried requiring factory_girl_rails in the spec_helper.rb.  I've tried modifying the spec_helper.rb w/

```
FactoryGirl.definition_file_paths << File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'factories')
FactoryGirl.find_definitions
```

The gemfile in the `core` contains `gem 'factory_girl_rails'` in the development, test groups.  I've even tried getting the factory to raise an error, but that doesn't even happen.  Therefore, the factory doesn't appear to even be getting loaded.  What do I need to do to get this factory loaded and registered?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's how we got around it.  As @Vinh Tran suggested, `factory_girl_rails` does need to be within the `Gemfile` of the app that you're working on as such:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

Additionally, the dummy app needs to be located under the `/spec` directory, although at this point, it doesn't appear to be populated with actual models, etc.

Finally, the `rspec` command needs to issued from the `boxes` directory as opposed to `core` directory.  All of these things combined have allowed us to successfully register a factory and have successful test runs.

Answer (score 16):

You need to help the dummy app (or the rails console) out, since FactoryGirl is going to look in Rails.root, which is spec/dummy.

So, from a console launched in spec/dummy for example just do this:

```
FactoryGirl.definition_file_paths = %w(../factories)
FactoryGirl.find_definitions
# You can use this line to see what factories are loaded
# FactoryGirl.factories
```

For your particular case, you'll need to change the actual locations, but where you are, if FactoryGirl isn't finding your factories, it's because it doesn't know where to look.

To be specific: Here is what I did.  My needs were as follows -  I needed to run rspec from the Gem root directory. But I also need to be able to run the rails console from the embedded dummy project and access Factory girl for convenient test object creation during development.

***TLDR*** Add this code into your dummy app's application.rb

```
 console do
   FactoryGirl.definition_file_paths << Pathname.new("../factories")
   FactoryGirl.definition_file_paths.uniq!
   FactoryGirl.find_definitions
 end

├── spec
│   ├── dummy
│   │   ├── app
│   │   ├── bin
│   │   ├── config
│   │   │   ├── environments
│   │   │   ├── initializers
│   │   │   ├── locales
│   │   │   ├── application.rb << This is the file to add the lines in.
```

The releveant bits of my application layout looks like

```
├── app
├── bin
├── config
├── lib
├── spec
│   ├── dummy
│   │   ├── app
│   │   ├── bin
│   │   ├── config
│   │   │   ├── environments
│   │   │   ├── initializers
│   │   │   ├── locales
│   │   │   ├── application.rb
│   │   │   ├── boot.rb
│   │   │   ├── database.yml
│   │   │   ├── environment.rb
│   │   │   └── routes.rb
...
│   ├── factories
│   │   └── models
│   │       └── api_requests.rb
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── controllers
│   │   │   ├── controller_spec.rb
│   │   │   └── session__spec.rb
│   │   └── my_spec.rb
│   ├── support
│   └── vcr
│   ├── spec_helper.rb

├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── mygem.gemspec  << this is the file to include the factory-girl-rails gem
```

I'm including the factory-girl-rails gem in my gemspec only and only in that location.
Nothing in my Gemfile, and nothing in the Gemfile for the dummy app.

```
  s.add_development_dependency 'rspec-rails'
  s.add_development_dependency 'capybara'
  s.add_development_dependency 'factory_girl_rails'
  s.add_development_dependency 'shoulda'
  s.add_development_dependency 'vcr'
  s.add_development_dependency 'byebug'
  s.add_development_dependency 'better_errors'
  s.add_development_dependency 'binding_of_caller'
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this when my spec didn't end with `_spec.rb`. RubyMine ran the unit test without any problem, and everything worked except for Factory Girl.

Answer (score 1):

2 things you can try:

- putting the `gem 'factory_girl_rails'` inside the `boxes` app
- create a sample rspec inside the core with factory and run it

I think your `boxes` app doesn't load the gems from the core, it just load the business logic

Comment: Thank you!  I'll give this a shot in a bit. I've been re-purposed for the moment.

Comment: I apologize about the delay, but putting the gem in the boxes app didn't have any impact.  rspec works within the core when using a factory.

Comment: what error did you get when putting the gem inside `boxes` app? same error `FactoryNotRegistered`?

Comment: same error.  A coworker has figured out the solution.  I'll be posting soon.